# Aligning numbers inside a table

Tags: tables, alignment

I am new to LATEX and I am currently writing my project thesis for my B.tech degree in LATEX using TeXstudio and MiKTeX. In my work, I want to create a table to represent the data. 
I used following code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\rmdefault}
\usepackage[top=1in,bottom=1in,left=1.25in,right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{table}[]
            \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
                \begin{tabular}{@{}cccc@{}}
                    \toprule
                    \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Batch}} &
                    \textbf{Ratio} &
                    \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Concentration 1\\ (mole/L)\end{tabular}} &
                    \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Concentration 2\\ (mole/L)\end{tabular}} \\ \midrule
                    1 & 10 : 1   & 55.55 & 5.555 \\
                    2 & 1 : 1    & 7.8   & 7.8   \\
                    3 & 1 : 10   & 0.61  & 6.1   \\
                    4 & 1 : 1.43 & 1.134 & 0.795 \\ \bottomrule
                \end{tabular}%
            }
        \end{table}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

My output looks like: [image]
All I want is to align the **Ratio** column with ':' in the center as:

[image]

Any help will be very useful to me.

Thank you. Keerthi vasan M

Comment: Don't use `resizebox` on a table. This will lead to inconsistent font size.

Comment: Also, remove the `center` environment around the `table`. If you want to horizontally center the table, use `\centering` inside of the `table` environment instead.

Comment: @leandriis thanks, I'll follow these.

Answer (score 4):

Welcome! One simpleminded approach is to make it three columns. I'd also use `S` columns for the last three columns, and avoid `\resizebox`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\rmdefault}
\usepackage[top=1in,bottom=1in,left=1.25in,right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{@{}cr@{}c@{}lSSS@{}}
      \toprule
      \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Batch}} &
      \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Ratio}} &
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Concentration 1\\ (mole/L)\end{tabular}}} &
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Concentration 2\\ (mole/L)\end{tabular}}} \\ 
      \midrule
      1 & 10 & : & 1   & 55.55 & 5.555 \\
      2 & 1 & : & 1    & 7.8   & 7.8   \\
      3 & 1 & : & 10   & 0.61  & 6.1   \\
      4 & 1 & : & 1.43 & 1.134 & 0.795 \\ \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}%
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or with some small amount of breathing space and auto-inserted colons.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\rmdefault}
\usepackage[top=1in,bottom=1in,left=1.25in,right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{@{}cr@{\,:\,}lSSS@{}}
      \toprule
      \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Batch}} &
      \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Ratio}} &
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Concentration 1\\ (mole/L)\end{tabular}}} &
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Concentration 2\\ (mole/L)\end{tabular}}} \\ 
      \midrule
      1 & 10   & 1   & 55.55 & 5.555 \\
      2 & 1   & 1    & 7.8   & 7.8   \\
      3 & 1   & 10   & 0.61  & 6.1   \\
      4 & 1   & 1.43 & 1.134 & 0.795 \\ \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}%
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks you @Schrödinger's cat for your answer. It looks good now. But I think I am investing too much of time in formetting tables rather than concentrating in the content. Is there any software to carry this minute formatting and provide the final latex statements like https://www.tablesgenerator.com/?

Comment: @Keerthivasan: Automatically generated code for tables alsmost always need manual adjustments.

Comment: @Keerthivasan You are welcome and I do not know if there is software, nor how good it is. My personal attitude is that the best tables are avoided tables. ;-) This might sound like a joke, but when was the last time you had a phone book in your hands/claws? I think nowadays it makes more sense to make the data available electronically and use other means of visualizing it. But this is just an opinion.

Comment: @leandriis yes it is. This part of LATEX is always very tedious.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat yes I agree. But avoiding it every time in a thesis writing is not encouraged.

Comment: @Keerthivasan There is not much I can say. If you really have lots of tables and want to just typeset them from some data files, `pgfplotstable` might come handy. The more so since you could then use `pgfplots` to plot some selected data. True, the tables may not be tuned to the end, nor fancy, but you might have an easier time converting data to human/cat readable output.

Answer (score 0):

By the easiest way, you can change the alignment option for each column (center left center center):

`\begin{tabular}{ c l c c}`

and you'll get the right alignment in the column.
No `\centering` inside the tabular parameters.

Comment: I not understand also the italian language :-), but in this way it is only a comment for my humble opinion.

Comment: I wanted to reply by suggesting the easiest way to change the options in the tabular enviroment. O.o